# Triple DES decryption returns wrong first 16 bytes of when decrypted again

Tags: encryption, go, tripledes

I have a problem with decryption when I try to decrypt the same byte slice again.

Example of code for clarification:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/des"
)

const (
    // tripleKey is TripleDES key string (3x8 bytes)
    tripleKey = "12345678asdfghjkzxcvbnmq"
)

var (
    encrypter cipher.BlockMode
    decrypter cipher.BlockMode
)

func init() {
    // tripleDESChiper is chiper block based on tripleKey used for encryption/decryption
    tripleDESChiper, err := des.NewTripleDESCipher([]byte(tripleKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // iv is Initialization Vector used for encrypter/decrypter creation
    ciphertext := []byte("0123456789qwerty")
    iv := ciphertext[:des.BlockSize]

    // create encrypter and decrypter
    encrypter = cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(tripleDESChiper, iv)
    decrypter = cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(tripleDESChiper, iv)
}

func main() {
    message := "12345678qwertyuia12345678zxcvbnm,12345678poiuytr"
    data := []byte(message)
    hash := encrypt(data)

    decoded1 := decrypt(hash)
    decoded2 := decrypt(hash)
    decoded3 := decrypt(hash)
    decoded4 := decrypt(hash)


    fmt.Printf("encrypted data :             %x\n", data)
    fmt.Printf("1 try of decryption result : %x\n", decoded1)
    fmt.Printf("2 try of decryption result : %x\n", decoded2)
    fmt.Printf("3 try of decryption result : %x\n", decoded3)
    fmt.Printf("4 try of decryption result : %x\n", decoded4)
}

func encrypt(msg []byte) []byte {
    encrypted := make([]byte, len(msg))
    encrypter.CryptBlocks(encrypted, msg)

    return encrypted
}

func decrypt(hash []byte) []byte {
    decrypted := make([]byte, len(hash))
    decrypter.CryptBlocks(decrypted, hash)

    return decrypted
}
```

This code is also available and runnable
on [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/o0uWrm3MMV).

It gives the following result:

```
encrypted data :             313233343536373871776572747975696131323334353637387a786376626e6d2c3132333435363738706f6975797472
1 try of decryption result : 313233343536373871776572747975696131323334353637387a786376626e6d2c3132333435363738706f6975797472
2 try of decryption result : 5e66fa74456402c271776572747975696131323334353637387a786376626e6d2c3132333435363738706f6975797472
3 try of decryption result : 5e66fa74456402c271776572747975696131323334353637387a786376626e6d2c3132333435363738706f6975797472
4 try of decryption result : 5e66fa74456402c271776572747975696131323334353637387a786376626e6d2c3132333435363738706f6975797472
```

As you can see the first decryption works well and returns valid result,
but all other tries returns the wrong result.
The first 16 bytes of result is not as in source byte slice.

Can somebody describe what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version: don't reuse the decrypter object.

Longer version: You're using a cipher in CBC mode: when encrypting the data, the plaintext for block N is XOR-ed with the ciphertext for block N-1 (or the IV, on the first block). On decryption this is done in reverse.

This means that when you try and reuse your decrypter object you don't get the correct results because the state isn't correct - it is decrypting the blocks as if they were subsequent blocks in your message. A peculiarity of CBC is that an incorrect IV will only affect the first decrypted block.

Comment: Frederick, thanks a lot! I just rewrite my code for creating new decrypter for each iteration and now it works fine.

Comment: Do you have an example of that, Yury?